# Is PHP PDO capable of advanced bindings?

Tags: php, data-binding, pdo

Can PHP PDO extension **bind nested objects automatically**? I mean using foreign key to bind automagically`messages` array to a collection of `Message` instances:

```
class User
{
   public $id, $name;
   public messages = array();
}

class Message { public $id, $content }

----------------------------   -------------------------------------------
| Table user   | id | name |   | Table message  | id | content | user_id |
----------------------------   -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can PHP PDO extension bind nested objects automatically? I mean using foreign key to bind automagically messages array to a collection of Message instances:

No, it can't. You could write a simple layer on top though that accomplishes that for you. PDO is a database *abstraction* layer. That means that it provides a consistent API to access multiple kinds of databases. It is not - in any way - an ORM layer. If you want something like that, look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/). These will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No. That sort of thing is the job of an ORM library.